# Send the request to Proxy server from Web server

Tags: proxy, network-security

I made a proxy server in python 3. It listens on the port 4444. It basically receives the request from clients and sends it to the server. I want to use it as a firewall to my Dvwa server. So added another functionality to the proxy. What it does is, before sending the request to the DVWA server, it validates the input.

But the problem is, the clients have to configure their proxy settings in the browser to use my proxy server. Is there any way to access the proxy without configuring the browser settings. Basically I want to host the proxy server instead of the original web server. So that all the traffic goes through the proxy before going to the webserver.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You don't say whether your Python3 proxy is hosted on the same machine as the DVWA.

Assuming it is, the solution is simple: *a reverse-proxy configuration*. Your proxy transparently accepts and forwards requests to your server who then processes them and sends them back via the proxy to the client.

1. Have your proxy listen on port 80
2. Have the DVWA listen on a port other than 80 so it's not clashing (e.g. 8080)
3. Your proxy, which is now receiving requests for the IP/hostname which would otherwise go to the DVWA, then forwards them as usual.

The client/web browser is none the wiser that anything has changed. No settings need changing.

That's the best case scenario, given the information provided in your question. Unfortunately, I can't give any alternative solutions without knowing the network layout, where the machines reside, and the intent of the project. Some things to consider:

- do you have a proper separation of concerns for this middleware you're building?
- what is the purpose of the proxy?
- is it for debugging/observing traffic?
- are you actually trying to build a Web Application Firewall?

Comment: I'm actually building a web application firewall. I want to use my proxy as a firewall. But no one sends request to the proxy intentionally right?. That's why I want my server to accept request if it is from proxy, else forward it to proxy so that the proxy validates the request and sends it to Web server again.

Comment: I think you might benefit from learning more about how different types of proxies work. There are legitimate use-cases where browsers explicitly forward their requests to proxies (i.e. a forward proxy). Alternatively, a firewall-like proxy would be installed on a gateway where any requests to a backend server have to go through it (i.e. reverse proxy).

Comment: This [article](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/cdn/glossary/reverse-proxy/) from Cloudflare (proxy experts!) illustrates the difference quite well. As does this [article](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/ddos/glossary/web-application-firewall-waf/) about WAFs.